# Tcl code to fetch pin details and compare with another file pins

Tags: tcl

I have two files and I am comparing specific lines between two files using the def function. **python** and I am trying to write same code on **tcl**

The file data is given below

```
PIN i_hbmc_ieee1500_sel_wir
DIRECTION INPUT ;
USE SIGNAL ;
PORT
LAYER K3 ;
RECT 2090.163000 3265.856000 2090.476000 3265.920000 ;
END
END i_hbmc_ieee1500_sel_wir
PIN i_hbmc_ieee1500_cap_wr
DIRECTION INPUT ;
USE SIGNAL ;
PORT
LAYER K3 ;
RECT 2090.163000 3265.984000 2090.476000 3266.048000 ;
END
END i_hbmc_ieee1500_cap_wr
PIN i_hbmc_ieee1500_shft_wr
DIRECTION INPUT ;
USE SIGNAL ;
PORT
LAYER K3 ;
RECT 2090.163000 3265.728000 2090.476000 3265.792000 ;
END
END i_hbmc_ieee1500_shft_wr
```

The **python** code to fetch pin details of both files and compare between files

```
   def readPinFile(filename):
   result = None
   with open(filename, "r") as file:    

    result = {}
    lastPin = None        
    for line in file:
        lines = line.strip()
        
        if lines[:3] == "PIN": 
            lastPin = lines.split(" ")[1]               
            result[lastPin] = {"LAYER": None, "RECT": None}
        
        if lines[:5] == "LAYER":
            result[lastPin]["LAYER"] = lines.split(" ")[1]
           
        if lines[:4] == "RECT":
            result[lastPin]["RECT"] = lines.split(" ")

return result

pin_of_file1 = readPinFile("osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.lef") #lef file1
pin_of_file2 = readPinFile("osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2.lef")#lef file2



with open("file04.txt", "r+") as output_file4:  #compare same pins with layer and location
 for pin, pin_data in pin_of_file1.items():
      if pin in pin_of_file2:
         if pin_of_file2[pin]["LAYER"] == pin_data["LAYER"] and pin_of_file2[pin]["RECT"] == pin_data["RECT"]:
             output_file4.write(pin + "\n\n")
```

The **TCL** code I tried to get the same output

```
proc fileinput {filename} {
set filedata [open filename r]
set file1 [ read $filedata ]
foreach line [split $file1 \n] {
      set pindata { PIN { LAYER {} RECT {} }}
      if {[string match *PIN* $line]} {
          dict lappend pindata PIN $line         
         }
      if {[string match *LAYER* $line]} {
           dict lappend pindata PIN {LAYER{$line}} 
         } 
      if {[string match *RECT* $line]} {
           dict lappend pindata PIN {RECT{$line}}
          } 
      }
  return $pindata
}
set fileinput1 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.txt]
set fileinput2 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2.txt]
```

In tcl I am trying to write comparing between the pins section (last 4-5 lines on python code), but I am stuck in the middle. I am fully confused to continue this code. can anyone help me to complete this code(mainly last 2 lines of python code)

```
  foreach $pin, $pin_data [gets $fileinput1]
    if{[string match $pin $fileinput2]}
```

This is the code I tried

Answer (score 0):

Your code is using a proc called `fileinput` but you didn't include the proc definition.   It actually looks like you are including the body of the proc, you didn't include the `proc` command at the beginning.

I will assume you want to do this (I also changed how the pindata dictionary is set)

```
proc fileinput {filename} {
    set filedata [open $filename r]
    set file1 [ read $filedata ]
    close $filedata
    set pindata [dict create]
    foreach line [split $file1 \n] {
        if {[string match "PIN*" $line]} {
            set pin [lindex $line 1]
        }
        if {[string match "LAYER*" $line]} {
            set layer [lindex $line 1]
            dict lappend pindata $pin layer $layer
        } 
        if {[string match "RECT*" $line]} {
            set rect [lrange $line 1 4]
            dict lappend pindata $pin rect $rect
        } 
    }
    return $pindata
}
```

Now the proc returns a dictionary with a top key set to the pin name and nested keys called "layer" and "rect".

To compare the pin layer of two different files:

```
# Parse each file and return a dict
set pin_data1 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1.txt]
set pin_data2 [fileinput osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2.txt]

# Iterate over the keys and compare layers:
foreach pin_name [dict keys $pin_data1] {
    set layer1 [dict get $pin_data1 $pin_name layer]

    # Check that the pin_name is in the second file
    if {![dict exists $pin_data2 $pin_name]} {
        puts "$pin_name exists in pin_data1 but not pin_data2"
        continue
    }

    # If we get this far, then $pin_name appears in both files.
    set layer2 [dict get $pin_data2 $pin_name layer]
    if {$layer1 ne $layer2} {
        puts "Layer mismatch for $pin_name:"
        puts "     1:  $layer1"
        puts "     2:  $layer2"
    }
}
```

By the way, your example input file is incomplete.   There is an END for a pin name that was never declared earlier.

Comment: In the above-mentioned files, extra pins with details will be present. I compared the same file with a different name (osi_hbmp_top_briscm_1, osi_hbmp_top_briscm_2) same data; its giving correct output.    When I use actual files it gives an error for extra pins. the error is posted on the answer page.

Comment: I edited my answer to check for if a pin_data1 pin_name doesn't exist in pin_data2.  

If you also need to know if a pin_data2 pin_name doesn't exist in pin_data1, then just iterate on the pin_data2 dict keys too.